# Why is the given hash function a poor hash function?

Tags: java, hash

Assume that the hash table is an array with indices 0 through HASHSIZE-1. The function returns a value in the correct range and does not generate any run-time errors. Assume that the passed in String has at least 2 characters. Why is it a poor hash function?

```
public static int hash(String key) {
    return (key.charAt(0)
            + key.charAt(1)
            + key.charAt(key.length()-1) % HASHSIZE;
}
```

Comment: It looks like there would be many collisions, which is poor.

Comment: check the distribution

Comment: It also seems to disregard the contents of most of the string, which is kind of useless.

Comment: Why not use String.hashCode() ?

Comment: This would also throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException on small strings.

Comment: @chatton OP says that strings have at least two characters, but I would agree that it still makes sense to bound-check before indexing.

Comment: my bad didn't see that last bit. Yeah the code should probably handle cases like that too.

Comment: It also doesn't compile. It is missing a right parenthesis before the remainder operator.

Answer (score 2):

The quality of a hash function depends on the number of collisions they create among the expected population of keys. Good functions make situations when different keys produce the same hash code less likely.

The quality of this approach depends on the expected length of keys in use. For keys of length three this is a perfectly acceptable approach, although it is not ideal, because hash does not change based on letter ordering.

For keys of length 10 this approach will generate collisions for all keys starting in the same pair of letters that have the same letter at the end. When the two initial letters and the last letter combination repeat a lot, you will get collisions, rendering this hash function less useful.

Comment: Additionally, the function will not use the full `int` range; the result will never exceed 196605, so if `HASHSIZE` is bigger than that, the upper part of the table will be entirely unused, while there are lots of avoidable collisions in the lower part.